# ¿Por que no me muestra el error personalizado?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Estoy tratando de que se ejecute este error personalizado al teclear pero no me sale

```js
window.onload = function(){
 var cedula = document.getElementById('cedula');
 cedula.oninput = Numeros;
}

function Numeros(){
 var cedula = document.getElementByid('cedula');
 alert("");
 cedula.addEventListener('invalid', function(evt){
  if(this.validity.patternMismatch)
  {
   alert(this.validity.patternMismatch)
   this.setCustomValidity('solo numeros');
  }
 });
 cedula.addEventListener('input', function(evt){
  this.setCustomValidity('');
 });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "es">
<head>
 <meta charset = "UTF-8">
 <title>Formulario de registro</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/reg.css">
 <script src = "../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src = "../js/validar1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Formulario de registro</h1>
 <form  method= "post" class = "form-registro">
  <h2> Crear capitanes</h2>
  <div class ="contenedor-input">
   <input type = "text" pattern = "[0-9]" id = "cedula" name = "cedula" placeholder = "Cedula" class = "input-100" required>
   <input type = "button" value = " Registrar capitan" class = "btn-enviar" id = "btn-enviar">
  </div>  
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

La verdad no se que se que estoy haciendo mal, agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes los siguientes errores:

1. En la línea `cedula.oninput = Numeros;` lo que estas haciendo es asignar al evento `input` una función que, si la revisas, suscribe mas eventos. Es decir que cada vez que se ingresen valores al `input`, agregas más y más `listeners` sobre el `input`, lo que eventualmente provocara que se *"cuelgue"* el navegador.
2. Para que aparezcan los mensajes de error es necesario `"Enviar"` (`eg: submit`) el formulario. Es decir que tu `<input type="button"`, en realidad debería ser `<input type = "submit"`.

### Solución:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var cedula = document.getElementById('cedula');
  cedula.oninput = Numeros;
}

function Numeros() {
  if (this.validity.patternMismatch) {
    this.setCustomValidity('solo numeros');
  } else {
    this.setCustomValidity('');
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Formulario de registro</h1>
<form method="post" class="form-registro">
  <h2> Crear capitanes</h2>
  <div class="contenedor-input">
    <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]" id="cedula" name="cedula" placeholder="Cedula" class="input-100" required>
    <input type="submit" value=" Registrar capitan" class="btn-enviar" id="btn-enviar">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda,e sirvió a la perfección

Answer (score 0):

no has pensado hacer algo mas facil como esta pequeña validacion con jquery  :

```js
$("#button").submit(function () {  
    if($("cedula").val().length < 1) {  
        alert("solo numeros");  
        return false;  
    }  
    return false;  
});
```

Comment: Pero es que no quiero usar alert para los errores quiero usar la API para hacer esas validaciones

Comment: cual es la API? su nombre, en la pregunta no dices su nombre, solamente veo que usas jquery y un script llamado validar1 supuse que ese era tu script que estas haciendo

Comment: Bueno esa API es para validar formularios la verdad no se como se llama

Comment: mmmm ps si no sabes como se llama , comparte el archivo/codigo del script "validar1.js" asi te podre ayudar mejor.

Answer (score 0):

Si no entendí mal, lo que quieres hacer es validar que solo sean números los que se ingresen al text al ir escribiendo, yo lo haría así, espero y te sirva:
Nota: para validar que un campo sea solo numérico y a la misma vez darle formato, busca el plugin de jquery number format, y así ya no es necesario que muestres ese mensaje de "solo numeros"

```
$('#cedula').keyup(function(){
   var cedula = $(this).val();
   //lo que quieres que haga aquí
   console.log(cedula);//en la consola te irá imprimiendo lo que vayas escribiendo
});
```

Comment: yo le conteste igual, pero quiza no se explico bien ella

Comment: Y cómo se haría eso con jQuery?

Comment: Yo no quiero que me muestre un alert cuando digite algo distinto a un número, lo que queiro es que me muestre una mensaje como el que pone cuando uno pone el atributo required

Comment: estas empezando en jquery?

Comment: Si soy nuevo en jquery

Comment: @FamiliaValenciaHdz en el ejemplo que yo y valle50 comento usamos jquery, tu solamente necesitas copiar y probar en tu codigo, como vez en tu codigo usas jquery eso supongo que sabes usar jquery?

Comment: ahh, ya... también hay varios plugins de jquery para mostrar mensajes, pero en lo personal, esos mensajes de "solo números", llegan a ser algo molestos, es más fácil y cómodo utilizar el plugin que te comenté, y automáticamente  te valida que solo sean números

Comment: si eres nuevo en Jquery te recomiendo ver la documentacion de jquery

Comment: @valle50 lo se pero la pregunta del usuario usa alert

Comment: Lo que quiero es eso que solo puedan usar números, en ese campo, pero no me gusta como queda el campo cuando el imputado es type number

Comment: Pero este es un archivo que se baja y ser incluye en el HTML???

Comment: sí, así es, es un archivo que me parece que se llama numberformat.js, se incluye después del de jquery para que funcione, hay documentación sobre cómo usarlo, y para los mensajes que quieres puedes buscar el plugin que se llama alertify js